# Eagle - multisized capacitor connection issue

Tags: eaglecad, pad

I'm quite new to Eagle and currently ran into a problem with the multi-sized capacitor package in Eagle. The board layout is shown below.

[image]

As you can see pin 2 and pin 3 should in theory be connected, however there is simply no way for me to make this connection. In the schematics the symbol looks like an ordinary capacitor with 2 connections.

[image]

I tried to use the invoke command as the Internet has suggested but that gives me an error 'Part only has 1 gate :c4'. I tried to edit the package itself but the package is from the default Eagle library rcl and I can't seem to edit the packages from there. The part name is C025_050-025X075 from rcl, if that helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Three ways to achieve the goal comes to mind:

- wrong way, but working:

  - how: put two cap devices onto circuit diagram each with needed package, connect them in parallel, and then "overlap" them on the board;
  - pros: quick and dirty way;
  - cons: will cause "overlap" error in DRC; most probably duplicate drillings on the excellon file so board manufacturer will have to rework it; and you will just look as a person not following EAGLE usage guidelines or even being ignorant.
- compliant way, but not good one (the one you seem have used):

  - how: you put additonal pad *at the board level*, draw silkscreen at the board level, then name added pad the same as wire name you want to connect it to using *Name* tool;
  - pros: relatively easy and intuitive way, you immediately see the result on the board;
  - cons: as added pad and silkscreen drawing are not part of the device, when moving device you will have to also move these parts one-by-one (or use region select tool); if you will delete wire you associated new pad with, connecting new wire may give it new name, and pad will appear unconnected.
- right way, the best one:

  - how: you open library editor, create new custom library, copy one of the packages (the one you mentioned) into this library, edit the package adding one more pad in required location, then edit symbol adding one more pin naming it the same way as the pin you want to duplicate with "@1" at the end, then connect new pad and pin in the "device" view in library editor, then you save changes and voila - your new device is ready, you add it to the schematic, and pins with same name (one without and another with @1) will be suggested to be connected;
  - pros: totally compliant; you move device's elements altogether when moving the device, tool will always suggest you to connect the device *as you designed it to be*;
  - cons: a little harder than previos as you will have to switch between windows and create new library files; also requires understanding of connection between *device*, *package*, and *symbol*.